# android display dialogbox during progressbar

Tags: java, android, multithreading, dialog, progress-bar

I have this problem: during a long operation, I display a `ProgressBar`. Sometimes, during this operation, the programm has to ask the user for somewhat.
Then, I'd like to display a `DialogBox`, but if I do that, I get an error, since a `DialogBox` cannot be displayed during a `Thread`.

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: how r u showing a ProgressBar..in AsyncTask?

Comment: thats the problem..u cannot do UI related task on an another thread in android..use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) ..it is the exact solution for ur problem.

Comment: So, I tryed with AsyncTask, but it does NOT solve my problem. As soon I try to create a Dialog I get java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: OK, I got it. If I call the builder.create() and alert.show() in an runOnUiThread() Task I can display my Dialog. Now I just have to stop my task during this DialogBox is displayed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use AsyncTask Instead of thread then it will work you cannot perform UI related work in thread.

AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows to perform background operations and **publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers**.

**Read about AsyncTask**

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Android supports the usage of the standard Java Thread class to perform asynchronous processing.

Android also supplies the java.util.concurrent package to perform something in the background, e.g. using the ThreadPools and Executor classes.

If you need to update the user interface from a new Thread, you need to synchronize with the user interface thread.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Answer (score 1):

i think this is what u want.

To start the operation:-

```
new StartTask().execute("");
```

StartTask Class:-

```
    public class StartTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        private ProgressDialog pdialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

                // UI work allowed here
                pdialog = new ProgressDialog(syncContext);
                // setup dialog here
                pdialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                pdialog.setMessage("Updating...");
                pdialog.setCancelable(false);
                pdialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        if(pdialog != null) {
                pdialog.dismiss();
        }
        if(progress[0] == 0) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertbox.setCancelable(false);
        alertbox.setMessage("This is first Alert").setPositiveButton("OK",
                new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        pdialog.show();
                    }
                });
        alertbox.create();
        alertbox.show();
        } else if(progress[0] == 1) {
          AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertbox.setCancelable(false);
        alertbox.setMessage("This is second  Alert").setPositiveButton("OK",
                new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        pdialog.show();
                    }
                });
        alertbox.create();
        alertbox.show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String returnVal) {
            // UI work allowed here
            if(pdialog != null) {
                pdialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                //do some work here
                publishProgress(i);
            }
        }
    }
```